# Rails ActiveStorage url_for returns an URL which is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have an Employee model with an Avatar. I can attach an image to the avatar, but whenever I try to display the image, the

```
url_for(@employee.avatar)
```

produces a dead link. All I'm seeing is the value from the *alt* attribute from the  tag. The image tag I'm getting is the following

```
<img src="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--4786aa4d9d82d8f8d572b857965088b20fcb2f49/Portrait.jpg" 
alt="Thumbnail">
```

And I know the image has been properly attached. When I call the following, I get this result:

```
@employee.avatar
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007ff7e9ba41c0 @name="avatar",
@record=#<Employee id: 4, first_name: "Meda", last_name: "Burgdorf",  
created_at: "2019-03-03 23:03:00", updated_at: "2019-03-03 23:17:56">, 
@dependent=:purge_later>
```

as I can see the image in the storage directory
[image: Screenshot file structure]

Help is highly appreciated. Can anyone help me display the saved image.

Here is my setup.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
   has_one_attached :avatar
   ...
end
```

Content of my storage.yml file

```
local:
   service: Disk
   root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

My the migrations from Active Storage are migrated. See my schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_03_03_211537) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: `Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--76027e62bac321f7684b895d630ad9ecae8af821/CROPPED-Eva_Lottery.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-04 22:52:51 +0100`
To my understanding no error there.

Comment: @muistooshort: I found the error, though I don't quite understand why this broke the solution! In my routes.rb all the way at the end I had `#get '*path' => redirect('/')` which catched all unknown routes and routed it back to roots. By removing this line I now see the images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189420/discussion-between-fydelio-and-mu-is-too-short).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Active Storage appends the routes in the master route file, so they come after you catch all the routes. Better you can escape the active storage routes like

```
get '*path', to: redirect('/'), constraints: lambda { |req|
  req.path.exclude? 'rails/active_storage'
}
```

Comment: In which file do we add this and where?

Comment: This will be added in routes.rb file under config folder. Also this will be added at the end of the file.

Comment: This is a good hack but unfortunately opens up unfixable routing errors for anything with that prefix. For example, `www.example.com/rails/active_storage/404` - app-breaking, unhandled routing error.