# Rails 6: Catch all route constraint not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I placed a catch all route at the bottom of my route file. Annoyingly, Active Storage requests are also directed to the same action. I don't want that.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990363/rails-activestorage-url-for-returns-an-url-which-is-not-valid/55450163#55450163) on SO and this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31228#issuecomment-352900551) on Github that suggest adding a constraint to the route.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#...
  get "/*slug" => "profiles#show",
      param: :slug,
      as: "profile",
      contraints: lambda { |req|
        req.path.exclude? "rails/active_storage"
      }
end
```

However, this isn't working for me. ActiveStorage requests are still going to `profiles#show`. What is wrong with my constraint? Have I missed anything obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo.

It should be [`constraints:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) instead of `contraints:`.